# Capturing data packets from beacon using Altbeacon

Tags: android, altbeacon

I've a specific beacon that transmits data packets. I can see that Altbeacon library recognises this beacon (from minorId) and I can see that `packetCount is 1`, but what I cannot see is packet itself (from `Beacon` object). How can I do that? How can I get Beacon advertisement bytes - I know I can use `setDebug(true)` to see them in console, but is it possible to retrieve it in code programatically? How? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Beacon sends three things which you can capture using functions like beacon.getId1() which is UUID, beacon.getId2() which is major and getId3() which is minor.

Comment: It also sends byte packets. I need to capture them. How?